# The equation of a curve is $y = (x-8) (x-2)$. Find the gradient of the curve.

Tags: derivatives

**a) At the point when the curve crosses the y axis**

For this, I was thinking that when anything crosses the $y$-axis, the $x$- axis has to be $0$, so:

$(x-8)(x-2) = x^2-10x+16$ and using differentiation $f'(x)$ gives $2x-10$ and if $x = 0$ then $2 \times 0 - 10 = -10$.

My problem is getting the correct answer to the next part of the question

**b) At each of the points where the curve crosses the $x$-axis.**

For some reason I can't think of how I would find this out, I'm going to look at it again when I have more time later tonight, but it's on my mind and really bothering me how I can't grasp it.

Any assistance appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct for finding the points of intersection with the $y$-axis (then the $x$-**coordinate** has to be $0$). Now it's the other way around: the curve intersects the $x$-axis where the $y$-coordinate is $0$.

The curve corresponding to the equation
$$y=(x-8)(x-2)$$
crosses the $x$-axis when $y=0$, so when
$$(x-8)(x-2) = 0 \iff x = 8 \; \vee x = 2$$
So you're looking for the derivative in these two points.

---

Note that the term *gradient* is usually used in the context of functions of several variables; while you would just refer to *the derivative* for a real-valued function of one variable.